# SXA Filter search result by year

Tags: sxa

I have a search result component and want to add a filter to it in order to filter the results by year or by month.
i have a template that has a date field and i tried the Filter(date) component but it uses a facet that filters by a range of date, i want to filter only by either month or year
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible out of the box. We are not storing Months or Years in a separate field and that would be required to facet by one of those values.

To achieve that you would need to create a separate field in your item template which will store month or year or create a computed field which will extract month or year from the date field and store it as a month or year inside of the index.

The computed field can look like this:

```
public class ItemYear : AbstractComputedIndexField
{
    public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        DateTime date = EXTRACT DATE FROM THE ITEM;

        return date.Year;
    }
}
```

And here is the config part (it's for Lucene):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
                <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                    <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                            <field fieldName="year" returnType="int">NAMESPACE.ItemYear , ASSEMBLY_NAME</field>
                        </fields>
                    </documentOptions>                    
                </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
            </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```